# Java SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

I want to convert a date which may be several formats like yyyyMMdd,yyyy-MM-dd,yyyy/MM/dd to a standard for 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'. In the below code, I set the expected date format  to 'yyyyMMdd' and then passed in '2014-02-21'. I was expecting a Parse Exception but some how this is returning '2013-12-02 00:00:00'.What am I missing here ?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = sdfSource.parse("2014-02-21");
SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println( sdfDestination.format(date));
```

Comment: 4 answers in the same minute!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend adding `sdfSource.setLenient(false);` between the first two lines of that snippet.

What's happening here is that `"-0"` is being interpreted as the month, and `"2"` as the day.  With leniency true (which is the default) this is acceptable - `"-0"` is interpreted as the month before the first month; that is "December of the previous year".

Comment: Thanks, this worked. While I was trying to figure out this issue, I found this but some how I over looked it.

Answer (score 1):

The lenient property is set to true by default. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

```
sdfSource.setLenient(false);
```